# CDF - GoogleVis command for Cumulative Distribution plot

Tags: r, shiny, googlevis, cdf

Does anybody know what command/function from the GoogleVis package I can use to plot cumulative distribution functions (CDFs)?

Answer (score 0):

From [the journal article here](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-2/RJournal_2011-2_Gesmann+de~Castillo.pdf),

> The googleVis package provides an interface between R and the Google Visualisation API. The functions of the package allow the user to visualise data stored in R data frames with the Google Visualisation API.

You need to generate a data frame of the CDF for your PDF such as this example for `dnorm`:

```
xlist<-seq(-5,5,0.01)
ylist<-numeric()
for (x in xlist) {
  ylist<-append(ylist,integrate(dnorm,-Inf,x)$value)
}
df<-data.frame(xlist,ylist)
```

I'm not sure what googleVis buys you for visualization of this function beyond a simple plot:

```
plot(df)
```

or in one line:

```
plot(Vectorize(function(X)integrate(dnorm,-5,X)$value),-5,5,add=TRUE)
```